# Is there a way in PHP / html to make links open in the browser?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

Sorry if the question is a bit confusing, my problem is that with my current code:

```
$pattern = '/(([\w+]+\:\/\/)?([\w\d-]+\.)*[\w-]+[\.\:]\w+([\/\?\=\&\#.]?[\w-]+)*\/?)/m';
            
$str = file_get_contents('notiz.txt');
echo nl2br (preg_replace($pattern, "<a href='?url=$1' >$1</a>", $str))
```

every link is opened in the PHP desktop app, but i want it to open in the browser (Edge, Chrome, whatever). I'm still pretty new to PHP and html.

Edit: Here's a screenshot of[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooTnV.png) PHP Desktop Chrome.

Comment: What does "PHP desktop app" (take screenshot) mean? Where are you clicking the links?

Comment: Isn't a browser also a desktop application?

Comment: the point is that it's not supposed to do it in the (https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop?msclkid=f7e33ea1d03211ec9d08c31d5a4d3fc4) PHP Desktop Chrome App, but the browser

Comment: Does this work? `<a href="YOUR_URL_HERE"> target="_new">This is a link</a>` Let me know il add it as the answer if so :)

Comment: That only opened a new PHP Desktop, but still not the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and help of a friend i found a way that works. My question was probably confusing too. Here's the working code:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['url'])): 
                $cmd=sprintf( '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -window-size=1280,780 --app=%s', $_REQUEST['url'] );
                exec( $cmd );
            endif;
```

This makes sure to use Google Chrome in a new window to open the link when i click on it.
Thanks for all your help anyways.

Comment: Hey could you accept your own answer as the solution for future readers? This wil help them solve the problem as wel. :)

Comment: Not until in 2 days unfortunately, but i'll try to remember.

Comment: That's ok, I hope you do for completenes sake.

Answer (score 0):

In the browser you will need some help form JavaScript. Put the script below just
before the </body> tag.

```
<script>
            window.addEventListener('load', openLinks, false);
            function openLinks() {
                document.querySelectorAll('A').forEach((a) => {
                    window.open(a.href);

                });
            }
        </script>
```

When the page is loaded and rendered the function **OpenLinks** is looking for all **<A>** tags in your document and will open **each** one in a new tab with **window.open()**.

Comment: While it does open the links instantly, instead of using the browser, it just opens multiple PHP Desktops. But thanks anyways.